# CSS on website disappears when trying to print

Tags: html, css, printing, web

I have a website that I've spent a great deal of time programming, [www.omdyac.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20181112203710/http://omdyac.org/), and I recently tried to print the homepage of it, I expected it to just print what appeared on the screen, but when it printed I found this.
[image: Homepage]
[image: Lower down]
(Those are two separate images from the page.) Why does it seem that when I try to print this website that all CSS formatting disappears?

I got it to look like this by changing the media type from screen to all

[image: How it looks]

But this is how it should look, why doesn't the grey show up?

[image: How it should look]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `link` tags have `media="screen"` set. This means that the CSS will only apply onscreen and not when the page is printed. To make the CSS apply for printing also, set `media="all"` or just omit the `media` attribute. You can also set `media="print"` for print-only styles. Hope this helps!
EDIT: To save ink, browsers don't print backgrounds. I would recommend that you create a print stylesheet. For print, many elements of the page can be hidden, like the search box and navigation.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about that, seems pretty basic. I only code HTML and PHP, I never bothered with CSS

Comment: That sort of worked, but now instead of looking like [this](http://i49.tinypic.com/dvha1y.png) when I print it, it looks like [this](http://i46.tinypic.com/v4o6k3.png), why doesn't the gray show up?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you should read a little more about css and particularly about css media types (including print)
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp